# Android Studio creates this kind of overlay on top of everything else showing part of the code. How to disable?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-ide

[https://i.imgur.com/M4pgbiw.png[![Android_Studio_overlay][1]][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gusRg.png)

I sometimes get this randomly on top of everything when using Android Studio. These lines show randomly and the only way I have to remove it is by restarting the whole IDE.

Sometimes it's 3 lines, sometimes 6. Sometimes I can double-click on it and it takes me to that part of the code, sometimes it doesn't react at all if I click on it.

Right now, even if I minimize the Android Studio Window, this "overlay" is on top of everything else, even the Desktop.

I've looked online and the only thing that looks like it is the "code lens" option that appears when hovering the scrolling bar, but that's not it.

Does anyone know why does that happen and how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

follow the steps :

```
Editor -> General -> Appearance
find : Show Code Lens on scrollbar hover, and disable it
```

Second option would be : - If you right click on the scroll bar you will see checked the option "show code lens". Uncheck and you are good to go.

Comment: But I already said that's not it. I doesn't appear when I do that. It's similar to that, but it's not that. It sticks on top of it and doesn't matter what I do I can't remove it, and while having that on top, if I hover the scroll bar the Code Lens appears anyway.